# Struggling to import modules from scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having some trouble using the mannwhitneyu test provided by scipy. I think my problem is with importing. Here is my script:

```
SNPs=[]
Nonsense=[]

with open("final_positions_SNP_removed_duplicates_truepos_truetrans_normalized.txt") as fd:
    fd.readline()
    for line in fd:
        SNPs.append(line.split()[8])

with open("final_positions_nonsense_truepos_truetrans_normalized.txt") as fd:
    fd.readline()
    for line in fd:
        Nonsense.append(line.split()[8])

from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
u_value, p_value = scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(SNPs, Nonsense)
```

I keep getting an error that states: `NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined` I think I need to import scipy, but how?

Comment: this question has nothing with mannwhitneyu  function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
u_value, p_value = scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(SNPs, Nonsense)
```

You have imported `mannwhitneyu`, so you should use

```
u_value, p_value = mannwhitneyu(SNPs, Nonsense)
```

The reason you are getting `NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined` is that you did not import `scipy`, you only imported modules from `scipy`. to import `scipy` itself you would have to do:

```
import scipy
```

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. Thank you :)